# efficient Android storage move/insert operations on large ordered collections

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, save, sharedpreferences

I have a large ordered, unsorted collection. I would like to move some elements up or down in the list over large distances.
The list has to be persistent over sessions, any mechanisms such as SharedPreferences or SQLite will do.

Suppose the list is 1000 elements large.
I want to move the last element to be the second of the list.

```
 new      old
   1 ...    1
   2 ... 1000
   3 ...    2
   4 ...    3
   [ ... ]
 999 ...  998
1000 ...  999
```

That means I have to shift down all elements - which is instant in a collection such as ArrayList, but the problem is when I come to save the change to disk: I have to save the whole list which takes too long.

If I use a database I would have to push all elements below the inserted one - which seems stupid. Of course I could add an order field but then I would have to update all elements to add +1 to their order if they come after the inserted element - which seems as ineficient.

Or I could leave some large gaps between the order number such as:

```
 _id     old_order    new_order
   1           100          100
   2           200          200
 ...............................
 999         99900        99900
1000        100000          150 <- moved element to be the 2nd when sorting by order
```

Of course after trying to move to 2nd position about 6 or 7 elements - i.e. log2(order_gap), we end up with no space to move any elements there:

```
 _id     old_order    new_order
   1           100          100
   2           200          200
 ...............................
 994         99900          ???  <- no more room!
 995         99900          101
 996         99900          103
 997         99900          106
 998         99900          112
 999         99900          125
1000        100000          150
```

We would have to update again the order numbers for all the elements affected - so I don't like this solution either. Seems like a complicated hack that offers a limited optimisation.

My question is then: What is the best way to achieve efficient insert/move operations to large collections of data, by efficiency meaning: fast, minimal Android storage modifications?

Comment: If you are using a Collection(java) the best one to use would be Collection.swap()

Comment: To be nit picky-  shifting down all the elements is actually O(n) time in an array list-  its an array.  It's O(1) time in a linked list.

Comment: @IllegalArgument I am not swapping elements! Unless you want me to do 999 swaps. And the question is about the storage change.